# SVProgressHUD not appearing on my webView prior to loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, hud

I have the following on the following delegate

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [SVProgressHUD show];
}
```

But this is not doing anything, its not showing the HUD at all. Not before loading, during or after.

What am I doing wrong?

I have added the files to my project and imported my header file to my implementation.

Comment: when you initialize SVProgressHUD ?

Comment: is webViewDidStartLoad being called?